# mean of a variable if another variable = 0/1 and omit na (in R)

Tags: r, mean

so im using a dataset and want to find things such as mean, trim mean, median, percentiles etc. of "fluid" produced for both boys ("sex"=1) and girls ("sex"=0) and also omit data in which fluid = na.

help pls

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, that is an example data set and what code you've tried. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group columns by sum in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-group-columns-by-sum-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

aggregate(fluid, by=sex, FUN=mean)